# NodeMCU and Raspberry pi 4 home automation query

Tags: home-automation

I am a newbie in Raspberry pi. I recently learned to handle Websockets in nodeMCU ESP8266-12E. I wanted to know if this scenario is possible. Assume that in a house there are two floors and each floor has two rooms. In every room, I have 2 lights (one bright and one dim) one fan, and two 230V sockets (one is used for heavy appliances like a refrigerator). All the rooms in the house have the same electrical configuration mentioned above.  I was assuming to control each room with nodeMCU and then connect them to one Rasberry pi 4 2GB ram on each floor (maybe like a client-server type of connection). Both of these raspberry pi's will be connected to the wifi router. My question is-

1. is this possible to make such a logical connection?
2. would it be a nice idea to make my own HTML and android interface to operate such a connection? or use Home Assistant or other home automation devices?
3. Is this all efficient or just too much work? is there a better way to achieve it??

do provide links for me to read/research. Thanks

Comment: 1 yes, 2 depends on who you ask 3 depends on your skills and on who you ask. (I would use MQTT)

Comment: 1 complex and a Pi 4 is overkill for basic control.  Multiple devices lead to more config / debug work not always reliability. 2 if you have the time then do it else build on other packages (core part of FOSS) 3 - I would look to things such as Tasmota etc.  You are basically trying to reinvent the wheel.  Fine if you are happy to debug edge case errors with flickering lights or a warm fridge (warm beer is fine here in the U.K. but others object) and have plenty of time but if it's results you are after then bring in the skill set that's out there.